# Why does my CNN not predict labels as expected?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, siamese-network

I am new to the concept of Similarity Learning. I am currently doing a face recognition model using Siamese Neural Network for the Labelled Faces in the Wild Dataset.

Code for Siamese Network Model (Consider each code snippets to be a cell in Colab):

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input,Flatten

def return_inception_model():

  input_vector=Input((224,224,3))
  subnet=InceptionV3(include_top=False,weights="imagenet",input_tensor=input_vector)
  out=subnet.output
  out=Flatten()(out)
  model=Model(subnet.input,out,name="SubConvNet")

  return model
```

```
import keras.backend as K

def euclidean_distance(vect):
  x,y=vect
  return K.sqrt(K.maximum(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True), K.epsilon()))

def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    margin = 1
    return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.cast(y_pred < 0.5, y_true.dtype)))
```

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

base_model=return_inception_model()

left_input=Input((224,224,3))
right_input=Input((224,224,3))

feature_1=base_model(left_input)
feature_2=base_model(right_input)

lambda_layer= Lambda(euclidean_distance)([feature_1,feature_2])
output=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(lambda_layer)

model=Model([left_input,right_input],output)
model.summary()

Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
SubConvNet (Functional)         (None, 51200)        21802784    input_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None, 1)            0           SubConvNet[0][0]                 
                                                                 SubConvNet[1][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1)            2           lambda[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 21,802,786
Trainable params: 21,768,354
Non-trainable params: 34,432
```

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

[image: Siamese Network Plot]

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam

optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001)
model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss,metrics=[accuracy],optimizer=optimizer)
```

```
model.fit(x=[[train_nparr_pairs[:, 0], train_nparr_pairs[:, 1]]], y=train_labels[:], 
          validation_data=([[test_nparr_pairs[:, 0], test_nparr_pairs[:, 1]]], test_labels[:]), epochs=64,use_multiprocessing=True)
Epoch 56/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 118ms/step - loss: 0.5132 - accuracy: 0.4868 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 57/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 118ms/step - loss: 0.5044 - accuracy: 0.4956 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 58/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 118ms/step - loss: 0.5064 - accuracy: 0.4936 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 59/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 118ms/step - loss: 0.4806 - accuracy: 0.5194 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 60/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 118ms/step - loss: 0.4843 - accuracy: 0.5157 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 61/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 117ms/step - loss: 0.5060 - accuracy: 0.4940 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 62/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 119ms/step - loss: 0.5048 - accuracy: 0.4952 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 63/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 119ms/step - loss: 0.5110 - accuracy: 0.4890 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
Epoch 64/64
69/69 [==============================] - 8s 119ms/step - loss: 0.5118 - accuracy: 0.4882 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.4883
```

In the output, one can notice that the loss and accuracy are the same throughout the session. The value of val_loss is exactly 0.5. Also the val_accuracy remains as a constant value throughout the session. I have normalized the images yet still this happens. Is there any reason behind this output?

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem>?

Comment: Well , Previously I used to get val_loss and val_accuracy as 0.5000 for all set of learning rates and optimizers , but I don't get it now. Still, the val_loss remains 0.5000 and val_accuracy has a constant value ( like 0.4883 or 0.5117 ) throughout the session. Let me update the code here.

Comment: Why are you using such a small learning rate?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy It was mentioned in the answer given below. That's why I tried it

Comment: @TimbusCalin I have updated the code here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can easily remove the accuracy as a metric, since it is not relevant for your case (at least in the way `Keras` calculates the accuracy).

In Siamese Networks, the way in which accuracy should be calculated, is that you select a threshold, say `T`, according to your task, and if two images are the same and `similarity index >= T`, then you consider that a good prediction => +=1, otherwise do not increase the count.

But this is different from what `Keras` does, with `accuracy > 0.5` is considered a True Positive, you can remove it altogether, because the built-in accuracy metric in Keras is suitable only for typical classification problems.

That's for the first part.

The second part is that your weights are not updated accordingly. This is due to the fact that you declared the optizimer like this:  `optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1)`. The learning rate is too high in this case, particularly if we are talking about transfer learning what you applied with the pre-trained InceptionV3.

In summary:

1. Remove the accuracy as a metric.
2. Instantiate `optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001)`

Comment: Is there any sample code to set accuracy based on threshold in keras?

Comment: You would need to create a custom callback for this specific case, because it is not only the threshold but the class types (same vs different) that you would need to tackle in this case, not only change the threshold from 0.5 to 0.94 for example. Also, you need to train the network, see the results, see the embeddings, and only then pick a specific threshold, because this threshold is problem dependent